Why Jesus Said In John 4:24 That God Is A Spirit?
8-15-24
Thank you for these answers.
Love, Walter And Debbie

Sorry, but this isn't specific enough question. Please [edit] this to explain in detail what you don't understand about this passage.

Jesus declared that “God is Spirit”.

In John 4:24 Jesus is explaining to her that true worship doesn’t
require a temple or one to be Jewish or Samaritan. Rather it requires
spirit and truth. God is interested in who wants him in this way. (Rethink)

Jesus explained that true worship does not depend on the location but must be in spirit and truth.
This statement is one of the most profound statements.
Jesus is saying God is spirit which allows all of the following:

He's not flesh

He's not confined

to physical limitations
or locations
not bound by time
or space


He's invisible

He's omnipresent

He's transcendent

He's eternal

He's accessible



When Jesus says, “God is Spirit” he is saying that God is not flesh.
He is invisible, divine, and to a certain extent unknowable. But through Jesus, he has chosen to reveal himself. This means that for
those who worship him, they must do so in a spiritual way. This is why
Jesus speaks about the importance of being spiritually reborn in the
previous chapters (John 3:5). (Rethink)

Unlike humans, who are bound by time and space, God is omnipresent and transcendent. God can be worshipped anywhere and by anyone.
Furthermore, Jesus was teaching that worship should not be merely an external act but an internal and genuine one.
This teaching can be nothing less than revolutionary. At the time it shifted the focus from the physical aspects of worship, like the temple or the mountain, to a personal and spiritual relationship with God. This is the message of Christ.
Jesus was inviting the Samaritan woman, and all believers who get to read these words, to recognize that God’s presence is not limited to sacred spaces but is accessible to all who seek Him. In spirit and in truth.

This is a question that you should have voted to close instead of answered.

@curiousdannii That's very fair. Thank you for the feedback. The title question is indeed difficult to understand and the body of the question is sparse and lacks enough detail. Next time I will try to assess the clarity of the post so that the quality of the question is good before answering.

One can say that God is spirit in:

a generic sense, in which sense everything that is not material is spirit; now, angels are not spirits in this way, for even angels have something in them that is developable and perfect-able, for they aren't perfect (cf. Job 4:18), which only God is, and that which is developable and perfect-able (i.e. subject to development towards perfection) can be called some sort of matter, as Greek Aistotle comes with his idea of passive intellect perfectable by influence of God; or Egyptian Plotinus would say about "spiritual matter" that is susceptible to a perfecting divine influence, and, also a great Franciscan Bonaventura would say similar things about the spiritual matter. But in the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost there is nothing that is susceptible to development and to a perfecting influence, for Father is perfect (Matthew 5:48), and the Son is perfect (Hebrews 7:8) and as such also the Principle of perfecting others (cf. Matthew 19:21), and the Holy Ghost is perfect for all features and talents for which man can be called to be on a way to perfection is bestowed upon by the Holy Ghost (1 Cor 12:4-11), and He who is Bestower and Perfect-making, must be also the Principle of perfection and thus Himself perfect. Therefore, all hypostases of the Trinity, the Father, the Son and the Holy Ghost can be called "spirit" generically, as totally bereft of anything material in themselves, of anything that is developable, but all three of Them are eternally perfect and thus completely sprit.

in a specific hypostatic/personal, non-generic sense, which applies only to the hypostasis of the Holy Ghost who proceeds from the Father, and is called the Spirit of Truth (John 15:26).


For instance, the firm of "Coca-Cola" creates alongside with it also another brand - "Fanta" and (let's imagine) it also creates still another brand called "Beverage"; now, all three, Coke, Fanta and Beverage are generically speaking - beverages. But, specific brand-ly name "Beverage" belongs only to the third drink.
Thus, spirit is the Father, spirit is the Son, spirit is the Holy Spirit - generically speaking, but speaking in personal/hypostatic terms Spirit is the hypostatic name of the third hypostasis only.

This is a question that you should have voted to close instead of answered.

@curiousdannii Why? It is a question about a specific passage of the Scripture. Is not hermeneutics the very definition of it?

@LevanGigineishvili asks "*Why?". Because the body of the question is noise, all of which should be deleted, and the title isn't worded very well. If an item is closed without any answers, either it will be improved (e.g. rewritten and include explicit quotations) and reopened, or it will be deleted.  But with answers, there is no reason for the author to learn how to properly (for this site) ask a question.

John 4:24 Πνεῦμα ὁ Θεός
As is common with questions like this, English's strict a/the distinction poses a hazard.
ὁ Θεός we can take as a solid unit-of-sense. It's the same as when we say God with no definite article.
Greek doesn't always need to state the verb 'to be', but there is a slight difference when it doesn't. Dropping 'to be' tends to put the emphasis onto the subject and to imply the simplest possible meaning or equivalence.
God is spirit.
Or the King James Version and its descendants read a spirit.
For the explanation see the commentaries:
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/4-24.htm
This isn't a spirit (of which there are many). Or just a(nother) spirit - those are converses drawn in English. The original statement was more about God's worship not requiring a particular physical location.
John 4:21 - Jesus said to her, “Woman, believe me, the hour is coming when neither on this mountain nor in Jerusalem will you worship the Father.
John 4:24 - God is spirit, and his worshippers must worship in the Spirit and in truth.
That gives the simplest explanation: Jesus says God is spirit because his being omnipresent and immaterial means he doesn't have to be worshipped in some special sacred location that's going to need reconquering by the Messiah.
It seems to be a rule of online Hermeneutics that any verse that juxtaposes two persons of the Trinity will be dragooned into a Trinitarians-vs-non-Trinitarians argument, and those tend to revolve around the presence or absence of an 'a' or a 'the' in English. This one is too brief and too sidelong for anything much like that to be read into it.

This is a question that you should have voted to close instead of answered.

@curiousdannii I can't vote to close questions

@FelixLXX, see my comment to Levan Gigineishvili's answer.  Even if you can't vote, it's better to refrain from answering badly asked questions that can be improved.
